# GPEasy Potential PHP Issue

Tags: php, gpeasy

I was working on my webpage that uses GPEasy CMS, and I tried to install a new slider plugin via the download plugins option.

However once it finished installing the plugin my webpage disappeared and now only displays a plain white page (no error message), I can't relog into GPEasy as the link is no longer there.

From some research it seems like this might be a PHP issue?

Comment: check `short_open_tag ` option in your `php.ini ` it may cause a similar issue if the plugin is using `short_open_tag`

Comment: Turn on error reporting. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php